# Why fmp4 files can't decode the audio with VLC, but they can play normally with PotPlayer

Tags: c, mp4, h.264, aac, fmp4

I have an fmp4 file (using h264 and aac frame codes). When playing with VLC, only video has no audio, but the audio can be parsed with PotPlayer. 
The AAC format is ADTS.The screenshot of my fmp4 audio-related box is as follows

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mp4 should not have ADTS headers in the data. Just raw aac frames plus a configuration record in esds.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much